# Monitor a directory with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: .net, powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have a directory which is getting filled by some program. I would like to monitor this directory and check if files are continuously getting added to the directory. If for Example for 5 min no file is getting added to the direcotry I want to get notified. The Files are also getting deleted but i just have to care about the new files.
The script would run for about 20 min every three hours.
The code for the FileSystemWatcher:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\temp\test"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action {
   write-host "Created: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
   Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss" | Out-File "C:\temp\log.txt" -Append
}
```

I don't know how i could achive this, and I'm thankful for every input.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell scripts are not well suited to run continuously and report on events.

One way to achieve what you want is using a script like this:

```
[DateTime] $LastWriteTime = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\test" -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select -Last 1).LastWriteTime
if ($LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5))
{
    Write-Output "No files added in the last 5 minutes"
    # notify me...
}
```

and schedule the script in Windows Task Scheduler to run every five minutes.

It finds the newest file edited in the directory.

No need for a FileSystemWatcher

Comment: But what if some removes the file before you check?

Comment: @Richard - If someone manually deletes a file, the LastWriteTime will updated as well and may confuse thing. But I assume the OP just want to make sure there are always files written to that directory. You can always think of additional use cases which are not covered.

Comment: The script would only run for about 20 min, not 24/7. It's verly likely that the files are gone before you check, but i just have to make sure there a always coming new files. I will test you solution and report back.

Comment: The problem is, if files are deleted they are also edit the LastWriteTime.

Comment: Correct, in this situation, Richard's solution is more robust, I also thought about checking your logs but I liked the idea to not use a FileSystemWatcher at all. But with your requirements you may have to.

Comment: Depending on how the files are written into the directory, you could check for the newest LastWriteTime on any file, rather than the directory. Easy to do in PowerShell.

Comment: I changed my script a little to look at file dates rather than the directory.

Comment: If a older file is copied in it would't work, but I have to discuss with my colleagues if that would work

Comment: if new files have a certain naming convention, you could limit the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to just look at those.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a separate script running via `Task Scheduler` which uses your log file to see if a file has been created in the last 5 minutes.

```
$log = Get-Content -Path T:\log.txt 
$currentTime = Get-date
$5minutesAgo = $currentTime.AddMinutes(-5)
$FileAdded = $false

foreach($time in $log){
    if((get-date $time) -gt $5minutesAgo){
        $FileAdded = $true
    }
}

If($FileAdded) {
    Write-host "File was added in the last 5mins"
} Else {
    Write-host "No file added in the last 5mins"
    # Add in email code here
}
```

This will go through your log file line by line and check if the time was within the last file minutes. Then it will set the variable `$FileAdded` to `$true` if there was a file added. You can then use this to decide if an email should be send or not.

**Note**: If this is being run constantly make sure you roll over your log files regular to keep the processing down. As you are not including a the date in your log file you would have to roll over your log file at least once a day.

Comment: The script runs for about 20 min every three hours. I will test your solution and report back.

Comment: @N.R. Did you test this, how did you get on?

Comment: Yes I've tested it and it is working like expected. Now I have to present it to my colleagues and look what they say.