# Issues with Unzipping files problems

Tags: powershell, unzip

I have a PowerShell Script:

```
$path = "X"
$destination = "Y"

while (1 -eq 1) {
  if (Test-Path $path) {
    $shell_app = New-Object -COM Shell.Application

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.zip -Recurse

    foreach ($file in $files) {
      $zip_file = $shell_app.NameSpace($file.FullName)
      $copyHere = $shell_app.NameSpace($destination)
      $copyHere.CopyHere($zip_file.Items())
    }
  } else {
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is: I want the script to unzip all the files when it lands on the folder. But the script keeps on trying to unzip files it has already unzipped. Basically it keeps on looping. I want it to unzip all the file once it land on the folder and then stop the process.

Comment: Why not just remove the loop then? `while (1 -eq 1){`

Comment: I want the script to run as soon as someone puts a zip file in the folder.

Comment: Look at [filesystemwatcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888638/monitor-a-directory-with-filesystemwatcher) then

Comment: you could also remove the loop and implement a task for your script in your task scheduler which runs every minute.